# Displaying Gravity Forms Forms Outside of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

My client wants to use Gravity Forms to create forms - he is giving department managers access to the WordPress dashboard, then each manager will go in and create forms.  No problem there.

But, the client has a special interface for end-users (members) that is OUTSIDE of WordPress.  He would like to have the forms created using Gravity Forms to be displayed in this interface.  I can create shortcode or use the function 'gravity_form()' to call the forms, but then they are always displayed with the WordPress headers/layout/etc.

Is there a way I can access and display JUST the form?  (I've tried doing something similar to how the preview is displayed when you click the 'preview' option while creating the form.  But, I get the 'this is a preview' message).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try the following add-on which generates an iframe you can use to display the form on pages outside WordPress:

> ### [Gravity Forms Iframe Add-on](https://github.com/bradyvercher/gravity-forms-iframe)
>
> The typical process to embed a Gravity Form on a site where the plugin isn't installed requires:
>
> - Developing a custom page template with necessary code to output form scripts and styles.
> - Creating a new page in WordPress.
> - Inserting the form shortcode in the new page.
> - Manually writing an iframe tag with the page permalink and giving it a static height.
>
> With the Gravity Forms Iframe add-on, just enable a setting to allow the form to be embedded and copy the code snippet. That's it. As a bonus, the iframe automatically resizes whenever the form height changes -- for instance, when fields are shown or hidden due to conditional logic.